# Getting CMake Error: 217, when running catkin_make

Tags: ros, catkin-make, beginner-tutorials, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am going through beginner turotials for ROS indigo [link to tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) and I am getting this error message at point 5. Common step for msg and srv, when I run the catkin_make install or catkin_make commands. I've followed all the previous steps and even redid the tutorial in a new workspace.

***Here is the error message:***

```
cear@cear:~/daniyar1_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws
Source space: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws/src
Build space: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws/build
Devel space: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws/devel
Install space: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/cear/daniyar1_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/cear/daniyar1_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- beginner_tutorials: 1 messages, 1 services
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:217 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on the catkin package 'message_runtimes' which
  must therefore be listed as a run dependency in the package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:101 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/cear/daniyar1_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/cear/daniyar1_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

***Here is the package.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>

  <maintainer email="cear@todo.todo">cear</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>

  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>

  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>




  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

***Here is the CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   Num.msg
 )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(
   FILES
   AddTwoInts.srv
 )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES beginner_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtimes roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(beginner_tutorials
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/beginner_tutorials.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(beginner_tutorials ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
# add_executable(beginner_tutorials_node src/beginner_tutorials_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(beginner_tutorials_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(beginner_tutorials_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS beginner_tutorials beginner_tutorials_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_beginner_tutorials.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261766/getting-cmake-error:-217,-when-running-catkin_make/) by [Daniyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30390/daniyar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:217 (message):
> ```

```
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on the catkin package 'message_runtimes' which
  must therefore be listed as a run dependency in the package.xml
```

Notice how the error message says: `message_runtimes` (note the `s` there).

Your `CMakeLists.txt` has the extra `s`:

```
catkin_package(
  ...
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtimes [..]
  ...
)
```

The package is actually called: `message_runtime` (no `s`). And your `package.xml` also has the correct name:

```
<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

Remove the `s` and everything should be ok.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30390/daniyar/) on 2017-05-15**:
THANK YOU it worked :)
It has been a long day